# How can I request data with delay?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to create a Steam bot, that is requesting playerdata from CS:GO (I'm using [node-globaloffensive](https://github.com/DoctorMcKay/node-globaloffensive) for this).
Since I never done something with javascript I just tried it to solve like in php.

So I created an connection to my database, made an forEach row. There was the problem, that the script is requesting all data at the same time and I'm only getting my first one back.

So I decided to add some delay into with sleep(). 
That is actually working sometimes (before it had no problems with 7 requests, but now it just make 2 and restart it again after the setInterval()), but even so sometimes not... Thats why I want to improve my code now, so that my bot is nearly working without errors and a bit cleaner.

Thats my current code:

```
const SteamUser = require('steam-user');
const SteamTotp = require('steam-totp');
const GlobalOffensive = require('globaloffensive');
const config = require('./config');
const db = require('./database');

var SteamID = require('steamid');
var mysql = require('mysql');

let user = new SteamUser();
let csgo = new GlobalOffensive(user);

csgo.on('debug', console.log);
user.on('error', console.error);

var pool  = mysql.createPool({
  supportBigNumbers     : true,
  bigNumberStrings      : true,
  connectionLimit     : 100,
  connectTimeout      : 20000,
  acquireTimeout      : 20000,
  host                : db.host,
  user                : db.user,
  password            : db.password,
  database            : db.dbname
});

const logInOptions = {
  accountName: config.accountName,
  password: config.password
}

function sleep(milliseconds) {
  var start = new Date().getTime();
  for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
    if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > milliseconds){
      break;
    }
  }
}

user.logOn(logInOptions);

user.on('loggedOn', res => {
  console.log("Logged into Steam as " + user.steamID.getSteam3RenderedID());

  user.setPersona(SteamUser.EPersonaState.Online);
  user.gamesPlayed(730);

});

csgo.on("connectedToGC", function() {
    console.log("connectedToGC");

    const checkData = setInterval(()=>{

      //Delete friends from list if they are not in a official Steamgroup
      pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
        if (err) throw err;
        connection.query("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE SteamGroup1 = '0'  && SteamGroup2 = '0''", function (err, rows, fields) {
        connection.release();
        if (err) throw err;
          rows.forEach( (row) => {
            console.log(`${row.SteamID64}` + " got kicked.");
            user.chatMessage(`${row.SteamID64}`, "You got kicked, because you're not in an official Steamgroup");
            sleep(5000);
            user.removeFriend(`${row.SteamID64}`);
          });
          sleep(500);


    //Check connection to game coordinator
    if ( csgo.haveGCSession ) {

      //Check Database
      pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
        if (err) throw err;
        connection.query("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE (MainSteamGroup = '1' || CommunitySteamGroup = '1' || vip = '1') && BotInFriendlist = '1'", function (err, rows, fields) {
          connection.release();
          if (err) throw err;
          rows.forEach( (row) => {
            sleep(1000);
            var account_id = new SteamID(`${row.SteamID64}`);
            console.log(account_id);

            //Request Data from CS:GO
            csgo.requestPlayersProfile(account_id, function(ranking) {
                var rankid = ranking.ranking.rank_id;
                var wins = ranking.ranking.wins;
                var private = ranking.player_level;
                console.log(rankid);
                console.log(wins);
                console.log(private);
                sleep(1000);
                pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
                  if (err) throw err;
                  connection.query("UPDATE Users SET CSGOMM = '" + rankid + "', CSGOWins = " + wins + ", CSGOPrivate = " + private + " WHERE SteamID64 = " + `${row.SteamID64}` + "");
                  connection.release();
                });
            });
          });
        });
      });
    };
  });
  });
}, 100000);
});
```

Thats what it looks like:

```
Logged into Steam as [U:1:xxxxxxxxxx]
Sending GC message ClientHello
Sending hello, setting timer for next attempt to 2000 ms
Sending GC message ClientHello
Sending hello, setting timer for next attempt to 4000 ms
Got handled GC message ClientWelcome
Unknown SO type 2 with 1 items
Unknown SO type 7 with 1 items
GC connection established
connectedToGC
SteamID { universe: 1, type: 1, instance: 1, accountid: 2621xxxxx }
Sending GC message ClientRequestPlayersProfile
SteamID { universe: 1, type: 1, instance: 1, accountid: 1591xxxxx }
Sending GC message ClientRequestPlayersProfile
SteamID { universe: 1, type: 1, instance: 1, accountid: 1204xxxxx }
Sending GC message ClientRequestPlayersProfile
SteamID { universe: 1, type: 1, instance: 1, accountid: 2886xxxxx }
Sending GC message ClientRequestPlayersProfile
SteamID { universe: 1, type: 1, instance: 1, accountid: 1143xxxxx }
Sending GC message ClientRequestPlayersProfile
SteamID { universe: 1, type: 1, instance: 1, accountid: 4421xxxxx }
Sending GC message ClientRequestPlayersProfile
SteamID { universe: 1, type: 1, instance: 1, accountid: 1825xxxxx }
Sending GC message ClientRequestPlayersProfile
Got handled GC message PlayersProfile
Legendary Eagle Master
Got handled GC message PlayersProfile
Legendary Eagle Master
//and here it's just start again
SteamID { universe: 1, type: 1, instance: 1, accountid: 2621xxxxx }
Sending GC message ClientRequestPlayersProfile
SteamID { universe: 1, type: 1, instance: 1, accountid: 1591xxxxx }
Sending GC message ClientRequestPlayersProfile
...
```

How can I improve my forEach so maybe that it is waiting for the first request to end, then start the 2nd and so on...

I would like to give you all the infos you need :)

Comment: How about using promises?

Comment: Since I never used javascript I have no idea what this does and how it works

Comment: check your code, you have extra `'` in the query. plus, connection's within' connections = not recommended.

Comment: @Anuga Yeah, I needed that because the rank is an string, also how should I do that then, if I want to update it to my database?

Answer (score 1):

One problem I see with your code is that you are using a loop to "sleep", but this loop will block your server from receiving new request because javascript is single threaded.

A better way to implement an sleep function is to use async functions:

example:

```js
const sleep = (time) => (
    new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, time))
)

const asyncFunction  = async () => {
    console.log("First task")
    await sleep(1000)
    console.log("Second Taks");
    await sleep(3000)
    console.log('Final task');
}

asyncFunction();
```

Comment: Do I have to increase the await sleep() or can I use for everything 1000?